# How to create a table coming from a difference that can be used later in the same query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I was wondering if there's a way in which this code can work:

```sql
SELECT CD.COMPANYID
FROM COMPANYDEL CD

MINUS

SELECT CD.COMPANYID
FROM COMPANYDEL CD
WHERE CD.DELIVERERID = 57
```

I tried to use this method:

```sql
(SELECT CD.COMPANYID
FROM COMPANYDEL CD

MINUS

SELECT CD.COMPANYID
FROM COMPANYDEL CD
WHERE CD.DELIVERERID = 57) NameOfTheTable
```

Comment: What should be the purpose of this? Why not simply write SELECT company_id FROM companydel WHERE delivererid != 57?

Comment: It was just to know if it was possible to create in some way a table generated from the difference of two tables.

Comment: Use a `with` clause that can be reused in any part of the same query

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using unnecessary sub queries. This is slow and bad to read. It will be much better to just use the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT company_id FROM companydel WHERE delivererid != 57;
```

The critical point here is not to create a sub query, but to take care about `NULL` values (of course unless the column is not nullable). If the delivererid is `NULL`, this query will not select the companyid of those entries. If you want to get them, you need to change the query to:

```
SELECT company_id FROM companydel WHERE delivererid != 57 OR delivererid IS NULL;
```

or as another option replace NULL values by another value, as example using `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT company_id FROM companydel WHERE COALESCE(delivererid,0) != 57;
```

If you really want to do such an ugly "MINUS" like you asked, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT company_id FROM companydel WHERE company_id NOT IN 
(SELECT company_id FROM companydel WHERE delivererid = 57);
```